# chartjs not update using select option in laravel

Tags: chart.js

I have problem with my code that when I use select option in chartjs datasets

below is the html code

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <select name="tahun" id="tahun" class="form-control">
            @for ($i = 2021; $i <= date('Y'); $i++)
              <option @if ($i == date('Y')) <?php echo 'selected'; ?> @endif value="{{ $i }}">{{ $i }}</option>
            @endfor
       </select>
   </div>
   <div id="parent-canvas">
       <canvas id="chartpendapatan" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
   </div>
```

and the jquery code is below :

```
  const ctxpendapatan = document.getElementById('chartpendapatan').getContext('2d');
    const myChartpendapatan = new Chart(ctxpendapatan, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Pendapatan Desa',
                data: [],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
    var getData = function() {
        var tahun = $("#tahun").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('/grafik_pendapatan') }}" + '/' + tahun,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.result, function(id, value) {
                    myChartpendapatan.data.labels.push(value.nama_bidang);
                    myChartpendapatan.data.datasets[0].data.push(value.total_anggaran);
                });
                myChartpendapatan.update();
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Tidak Ada Data");
            }
        });
    };

    const brgy = document.getElementById('tahun');
    brgy.addEventListener('change', getData);
```

the output of my code is :
It's the data after I select year 2021

[image]

but after I select again year 2022 the output below :

[image]

first time whe I click year 2021, display 4 data in chart because in the database there are four data. but after I click year 2022, the data in 2021 still exist and data 2022 display also. so my question how to not display previous data after I select another year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You push to the labels and data array, if you dont want to show previous data you need to remove this data first or just entirly override the array:

```js
success: function(data) {
  myChartpendapatan.data.labels = [];
  myChartpendapatan.data.datasets[0].data = [];

  $.each(data.result, function(id, value) {
    myChartpendapatan.data.labels.push(value.nama_bidang);
    myChartpendapatan.data.datasets[0].data.push(value.total_anggaran);
  });
  myChartpendapatan.update();
},
```